# Non-live Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 release

Tags: server, 20.04

I am looking for a non "live" ISO for 20.04.3, [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-legacy-server/releases/20.04/release/) I can only find 20.04.1 non-live server(legacy-server), I can't install live server with packer.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 and then just update & upgrade all packages.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

This is equivalent to installing Ubuntu Server 20.04.3.